# Opencart change name when redirecting to paypal

Tags: paypal

Hi i want to change the name when redirect to paypal from my opencart store,i installed paypal standard and set up but i dont know how to change that name,thank you 
[image]

Comment: and one more question,how to make after a costumer pays with paypal the order status changes automatically to complete?For now is after a costumer buy a product the order status is pending  until i change to complete

Comment: Did the payment action is set to Authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Websites" is actually your business name, this can be changes from your PayPal account setting as I've list the step below ;

1. Go to PayPal.com and log into your PayPal account
2. Click “Profile” link in the top navigation menu.
3. Find and click the link “Business Information”. The field “Business Name” will be the name that is shown to customers in the PayPal hosted page. Enter your business name.
4. Save.

When you try to checkout, the business name you desired will be appear.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add costum fields in product?

Comment: Do you mean added a custom field in the opencart?